# how to create a normal html5 text box in kinetic js, without creating object "Kinetic.Text"?

Tags: javascript, html, text, kineticjs

May i know is there any other way to create text in **kinetic js** canvas but without using **Kinetic.Text**?

I found an example here and this is what i need:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-multi-event-binding/

```
function writeMessage(messageLayer, message) {
    var context = messageLayer.getContext();
    messageLayer.clear();
    context.font = '18pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
  }
```

but in this case we need to mouse over/ trigger an event only will show the text, once i remove the onclick/onmouseover function, the text wont show. i need something which can display text directly.

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: How about just calling `writeMessage` after KineticJS setup? Note that this is outside of KineticJS and will get lost should the canvas be redrawn.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but the text layer must be within the kineticJs canvas, some calculation and link is applied within kinetic js.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have and what you are looking for it do do? it seems that you just don't want the text to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EeBym/1/

I can't really tell what you are looking for, as you didn't explain it clearly, but if you are looking to add text to the page, there are various ways. On way is to add some JQuery to your page and an input field.

```
$('#words').keyup(function(){
    writeMessage(messageLayer, $(this).val());      
});
```

then you can bind the input field to a function which modifies the message layer.

If you don't want the text to disappear, just prevent it from being reset or cleared.